# how to put y axis greek letters in Veusz plot?

Tags: plot, veusz

I want to put Capitalomega with index DE and k [label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8Aww.png):

and then ı want to  show on the y axis label? How to do them?

Comment: In the Veusz plotting program

Answer (score 1):

Generally you can use tex symbols in Veusz. Therefore, you can write `\Omega_{DE}` and `\Omega_{k}` for your request. See details [here (Sec. 2.4 Text)](http://home.gna.org/veusz/docs/manual.html).

> Veusz understands a limited set of LaTeX-like formatting for text. There are some differences (for example, "10^23" puts the 2 and 3 into superscript), but it is fairly similar. You should also leave out the dollar signs. Veusz supports superscripts ("^"), subscripts ("_"), brackets for grouping attributes are "{" and "}".
>
> Supported LaTeX symbols include: \AA, \Alpha, \Beta, \Chi, \Delta, \Epsilon, \Eta, \Gamma, \Iota, \Kappa, \Lambda, \Mu, \Nu, \Omega, \Omicron, \Phi, \Pi, \Psi, \Rho, \Sigma, \Tau, \Theta, \Upsilon, \Xi, \Zeta, \alpha, \approx, \ast, \asymp, \beta, \bowtie, \bullet, \cap, \chi, \circ, \cup, \dagger, \dashv, \ddagger, \deg, \delta, \diamond, \divide, \doteq, \downarrow, \epsilon, \equiv, \eta, \gamma, \ge, \gg, \in, \infty, \int, \iota, \kappa, \lambda, \le, \leftarrow, \lhd, \ll, \models, \mp, \mu, \neq, \ni, \nu, \odot, \omega, \omicron, \ominus, \oplus, \oslash, \otimes, \parallel, \perp, \phi, \pi, \pm, \prec, \preceq, \propto, \psi, \rhd, \rho, \rightarrow, \sigma, \sim, \simeq, \sqrt, \sqsubset, \sqsubseteq, \sqsupset, \sqsupseteq, \star, \stigma, \subset, \subseteq, \succ, \succeq, \supset, \supseteq, \tau, \theta, \times, \umid, \unlhd, \unrhd, \uparrow, \uplus, \upsilon, \vdash, \vee, \wedge, \xi, \zeta. Please request additional characters if they are required (and exist in the unicode character set). Special symbols can be included directly from a character map.
>
> Other LaTeX commands are supported. "\" breaks a line. This can be used for simple tables. For example "{a\b} {c\d}" shows "a c" over "b d". The command "\frac{a}{b}" shows a vertical fraction a/b.
>
> Also supported are commands to change font. The command "\font{name}{text}" changes the font text is written in to name. This may be useful if a symbol is missing from the current font, e.g. "\font{symbol}{g}" should produce a gamma. You can increase, decrease, or set the size of the font with "\size{+2}{text}", "\size{-2}{text}", or "\size{20}{text}". Numbers are in points.
>
> Various font attributes can be changed: for example, "\italic{some italic text}" (or use "\textit" or "\emph"), "\bold{some bold text}" (or use "\textbf") and "\underline{some underlined text}".
>
> Example text could include "Area / \pi (10^{-23} cm^{-2})", or "\pi\bold{g}".
>
> Veusz plots these symbols with Qt's unicode support. You can also include special characters directly, by copying and pasting from a character map application. If your current font does not contain these symbols then you may get a box character.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer OmG posted, you can also directly enter the character (via a character map application or copy and paste), as Veusz supports unicode characters.